# Angular access parent template element ref

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that within that TS file I get the element ref as follows:

```
@ViewChild("custContainer") _custContainer: ElementRef;
const height = this._custContainer.nativeElement.height;
```

I then have a child component where I need to access this parent ElementRef.  How can I do this in the child component and I believe I need to get it once the parent is rendered as I am using it to get the height once data is loaded into this element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the height inside the child component then you can use `@Input` property in the child component.

In child component

.ts

```
@Input() height;
```

And from the parent component html

```
<child-comp [height]="height"></child-comp>
```